# How to make the horizontal lines and arc be aligned top in the quantifier symbol from the frege package with bguq option?

Tags: alignment

First an MWE and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[bguq]{frege}

\begin{document}

\[\Fquant[1]{a}\Phi(\mathfrak{a})\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the horizontal lines and arc below the fraktur a are not aligned top. **Then how to make the horizontal lines and arc be aligned top in the quantifier symbol, or how to make the arc be lower?**

Tips: the horizontal lines and arc in the package definition are two separate parts, but I don't know how to get my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will lower the arc symbol on all "quant" commands.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[bguq]{frege}
\let\oldbguq\bguq
\renewcommand{\bguq}{\raisebox{-0.03ex}{$\oldbguq$}}%lower arc

\begin{document}
    
    \[\Fquant[1]{a}\Phi(\mathfrak{a})\]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the (newer) [grundgesetze](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/grundgesetze) package instead for Frege's notation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{grundgesetze}

%for slightly longer horizontals; not required
\setlength{\GGbeforelen}{0.5em}\setlength{\GGafterlen}{0.5em}

\begin{document}
\[\GGall{a}\Phi(\mathfrak{a})\]
\end{document}
```

[image: grungesetze quantifier]